# ORDER BY count and Bitmap Heap Scan

Tags: postgresql, order-by, count, syntax

I have a table with *hits*:

```
    Column    |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     
--------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                     | not null default nextval('hits_id_seq'::regclass)
 link_id      | integer                     | 
 country_code | character varying(10)       | 
 created_at   | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
 "hits_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
 "hits_created_at_link_id_idx" btree (created_at, link_id)
 "index_hits_on_country_code" btree (country_code)
 "index_hits_on_link_id" btree (link_id)
```

This could be some samples in there:

```
    id    | link_id | country_code |        created_at         
----------+---------+--------------+---------------------------
 31084701 |      42 | IS           | 2015-04-24 11:01:11.30736
 31084705 |      42 | ES           | 2015-04-24 11:01:12.5688
 31084745 |      42 | LS           | 2015-04-24 11:01:25.1832
 31084943 |      42 | CX           | 2015-04-24 11:02:27.62448
 31085010 |      42 | KH           | 2015-04-24 11:02:48.7536
 31085053 |      42 | GL           | 2015-04-24 11:03:02.31408
 31085361 |      42 | KW           | 2015-04-24 11:04:39.44496
 31085590 |      42 | KY           | 2015-04-24 11:05:51.6624
 31085591 |      42 | BI           | 2015-04-24 11:05:51.97776
 31085675 |      42 | BS           | 2015-04-24 11:06:18.468
```

I don't understand why PostgreSQL handles these two queries differently (just the `ORDER BY` is rephrased!):

**Version 1:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count, link_id 
FROM "hits" 
WHERE ("hits"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-08-31 00:00' AND '2015-09-30 00:00') 
GROUP BY "hits"."link_id"  
ORDER BY "hits"."count" DESC, "hits"."link_id" ASC 
LIMIT 50;
                                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=991019.75..991019.78 rows=9 width=47) (actual time=3207.509..3207.514 rows=50 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=991019.75..991019.78 rows=9 width=47) (actual time=3207.506..3207.508 rows=50 loops=1)
     Sort Key: (count(hits.*)) DESC, link_id
     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=991019.52..991019.61 rows=9 width=47) (actual time=3207.458..3207.474 rows=100 loops=1)
           Group Key: link_id
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on hits  (cost=171847.85..930276.63 rows=8099052 width=47) (actual time=558.989..1943.812 rows=8219178 loops=1)
                 Recheck Cond: ((created_at >= '2015-08-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 6920
                 Heap Blocks: exact=25935 lossy=26518
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on hits_created_at_idx  (cost=0.00..169823.09 rows=8099052 width=0) (actual time=554.124..554.124 rows=8219178 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2015-08-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
 Planning time: 0.257 ms
 Execution time: 3207.846 ms
(14 rows)

Time: 3208,876 ms
```

**Version 2:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count, link_id 
FROM "hits" 
WHERE ("hits"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-08-31 00:00' AND '2015-09-30 00:00') 
GROUP BY "hits"."link_id"  
ORDER BY count DESC, "hits"."link_id" ASC 
LIMIT 50;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=327217.10..327217.12 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=2545.066..2545.071 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=327217.10..327217.12 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=2545.065..2545.065 rows=50 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC, link_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=327216.87..327216.96 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=2545.031..2545.041 rows=100 loops=1)
              Group Key: link_id
              ->  Index Only Scan using hits_created_at_link_id_idx on hits  (cost=0.57..286721.61 rows=8099052 width=4) (actual time=0.093..1429.205 rows=8219178 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2015-08-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                    Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.198 ms
Execution time: 2545.120 ms
(11 rows)

Time: 2545,832 ms
```

*Further background*

The first one is produced by ActiveRecord (Rails), but this seem not to perform best with PG due to the Bitmap Heap Scan.

```
Hit.group(:link_id).select('link_id, COUNT(*) AS count').order(count: :desc).to_sql 
=> SELECT link_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM "hits" GROUP BY "hits"."link_id" ORDER BY "hits"."count" DESC
```

Version: PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: What about `ORDER BY 1 DESC` ?

Comment: I don't understand how `ORDER BY 1 DESC` makes sense with my topic. Can you explain more in detail what you meant?

Comment: `The first one is produced by ActiveRecord (Rails)`. Depending on how this code was produced exactly, this might be a bug in AR.

Comment: With your explanation I don't think it's bug, it just enables easy scoping with the drawback of performance. Otherwise `order` needs to know about the `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Postgres allows "attribute notation" for a function with a single parameter. This can be used as substitute for [generated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34255739/939860). It's a legacy feature that's not used much any more. Details here:

- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166268/939860)

If this was not allowed, your first query would just raise a syntax error, since there is no column `"hits"."count"`.

One can reference input and output columns in `ORDER BY` (and `GROUP BY`, but *not* in `WHERE` or `HAVING`). While your *second* query references the output column `count` (the column alias for `count(*)`), the *first* query looks for an input column, since the column name is schema-qualified.

In absence of an actual column `"hits"."count"`, Postgres interprets this as `count(hits)`, which is the same as `count(hits.*)` like you can see in the `EXPLAIN` output:

> ```
> Sort Key: (count(hits.*)) DESC, link_id
> ```

And `count(*)` is implemented differently from `count(<expression>)`. The first only checks for the existence of a row (which is always at least slightly faster), while the second has to look at actual values - so the index-only scan we see for the other query is out.

This is one of the reasons why I keep advising against the use of basic function names as column name (or alias).

Comment: Awesome explanation! `count(expression)` makes sense for me in the case of expression is a column, as it can exclude NULL values. But is there a case `count(hits.*)` differs from  `count(*)`, beside the fact that it may slow down the query?

Comment: @Neonmate: I had expected that a row consisting of only NULL values would not count, since `(NULL, NULL) IS NULL` is `TRUE`. But lo and behold, it does not:
`SELECT t IS NULL /* TRUE */
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) t(c);` But:
`SELECT count(t), count((c))  /* 1 | 0 (!!!) */
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) t(c);` I am out of time now, but I'll have to follow up on this later ...